# MongoDB find query using $and and $nor operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection as below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658ad"),
    "lock_1" : ["desc_1","desc_2"],
    "lock_2" : ["desc_1"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658ab"),
    "lock_1" : ["desc_1","desc_2","desc_3"],
    "lock_2" : ["desc_1"]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658ac"),
    "lock_1" : ["desc_1"],
    "lock_2" : []
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658ae"),
    "lock_1" : [],
    "lock_2" : ["desc_1"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658aj"),
    "lock_1" : ["desc_3","desc_4"],
    "lock_2" : ["desc_5"]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55bec0793bed809b2cb658ak"),
    "lock_1" : [],
    "lock_2" : []
}
```

I have retrieved all the documents having "desc_1" in both "lock_1" and "lock_2" array by using below query, returning first two documents, which is correct.

```
db.locks.find( { $and: [ {lock_1 : "desc_1"} , {lock_2 : "desc_1"} ] } )
```

Now, I am trying to get documents which does not satisfy above condition. I tried using below query but it is returning last two documents.

```
db.locks.find( { $nor: [ {lock_1 : "desc_1"} , {lock_2 : "desc_1"} ] } )
```

How to retrieve documents where "desc_1" is either not present or present in one of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) operator which performs a logical **OR** operation and the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne) operator to test the contents of fields directly.

```js
db.locks.find({ 
    "$or": [ 
        { "lock_1": { "$ne": "desc_1" } },  
        { "lock_2": { "$ne": "desc_1" } } 
    ] 
})
```

Comment: I think this is better than my answer. Better use $ne than $nin in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.locks.find({ 
    $or: [ 
        { lock_1 : { $nin: [ "desc_1" ] }} , 
        { lock_2 : { $nin: [ "desc_1" ] }} 
    ]
})
```

reference:
[$or](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)
[$nin](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)